# When to use http status and why use it?

Tags: http, security

For public rest APIs, kinda understand since it gives better info, but it is necessary ? People still need to read the doc anyways ...

For protected(auth required) rest APIs, just 200 or 404 to prevent leaking important server stats?

Ex: Say i have a API endpoint, and authentication failed or other measure cause the failure of auth, should i send 401 code or just say 404 (or any generic code) to refuse the request ?

Comment: What is a "private rest API" in this context? If you mean "an HTTP server that only I connect to," then do whatever you want. You don't need to follow REST or HTTP standards or anything you don't want to. If you mean that you want other people to understand your interface, then providing status codes that match common usage (and the documented protocol) would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah that make sense, private rest api means a cloud server and API made for me and users

Comment: Bytes are bytes. Do whatever you want.

Comment: my bad i fix typo and bad wording of the question

Answer (score 0):

> Ex: Say i have a API endpoint, and authentication failed or other measure cause the failure of auth, should i send 401 code or just say 404 (or any generic code) to refuse the request ?

This is a very useful question, and for a private API the answer is 404. Give the caller nothing. Do not say "you were supposed to authenticate" or "your authentication was wrong" or "if you did something slightly differently, then this would have worked." For a private API, anyone connecting should know what is required. Anyone who doesn't should go away. Send then 404. Nobody is here. This is not an interesting endpoint. Stop scanning me.

For a public API, you want to help your caller as much as possible. Tell them the mistakes they've made and how they might fix the request to be acceptable. For a private API, give nothing.